# print an array with all the possible mean

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.5, mean

Suppose I have a list 'a'. Now, I want to print a list with all the possible mean(only integers) from all the possible pairs of list 'a'.For example:

```
     a = [0,0,3,4,1,2,9]
```

Now, I want to print a list b such that;

```
     b = [0,2,1,2,1,2,6,3,5]
```

If (a,b) is taken as a pair then (b,a) wont count. But it would count if there are duplicates of a and b present.

Comment: Do you want to round the non-integer means, or not include them

Comment: I haven't included the mean which are float. for eg : mean of 0 and 3 is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools
a = [0,0,3,4,1,2,9]  
av = [int(sum(i)/2) for i in itertools.combinations(a, 2) if sum(i)%2 == 0]
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you. summed up. can this be done without itertools?

Comment: Yes, you could just implement your own combination function, but using itertools is much easier.

Comment: yes, you'd just need to create a function that spits out all the combinations. Try it out and see what you come up with. Share what you did and post again if you get stuck. Also, @darxtrix's answer on this question should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements

Answer (score 0):

You have a few tasks to accomplish:

1. Given the input, output the combinations
2. Given the combinations output their means
3. Given the means, filter out the non-integers

Using functional programming style you can use function composition to put each step inside the other.

```
from itertools import combinations
from statistics import mean
a = [0,0,3,4,1,2,9]
b = list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), map(mean, combinations(a, 2))))
```